# Remote modules in Maven Master POM

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-3

I am trying to create Mavem master POM.

I  know that I need to keep modules inside the same project so that clean deploy happens.

But in my current requirement I have a master POM and a maven project which do not contain modules inside it but modules are on remote location. Is it possible to include such a remote modules in master POM. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to this `NO`. The modules make sense if you have them within the same location which means usually having them in the same SCM location (svn/git etc.).

Comment: sure will make POM with modules in same location